# Use of undeclared type error: Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have some Objective-C files with defined classes.

[image]

However when I try to create a instance of the class in Swift I get an error :
[image]

What should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Have you added objective-c bridging header?

Comment: I don't know anything about it. Tell me about it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be able to use Obj-C files from Swift project you should add Objective-C Bridging Header file. Create some `h` file and declare `import` statement for all necessary classes. Then in build settings find `Objective-C Bridging Header` item and set the name of your file

Comment: In the Objective-C bridging header, I see should I add it in Release section.

Comment: Yes you should add it to Release too

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark answer as solution to indicate that you have solved your issue

Comment: Hi @DhruvRamani, can you please share where exactly did you add your header file in `Build Settings`?? I've having similar error! thanks for your reply!

Comment: @BrunoSoko _In Build Settings, in Swift Compiler - Code Generation, make sure the Objective-C Bridging Header build setting under has a path to the bridging header file.
The path should be relative to your project, similar to the way your Info.plist path is specified in Build Settings. In most cases, you should not need to modify this setting._ <<- From the docs.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to merge `Objective-C` code with `Swift`. Therefore, you should use `Objective-C Bridging Header` in between. Detail information could be found in the official document:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html